# win32_networkaddressconfiguration no ip address

Tags: c#, networking, ip, wmi, system.management

I'm collecting all networkadapterconfigurations from the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class in C#.
I use this query:

```
private String strDetailedInterfaces =
                       @"SELECT * 
                       FROM   Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
                       WHERE  DHCPEnabled = 'TRUE'";
```

However, when selecting the networkadapter that I use to connect to the internet, it says that `IPEnabled = false` and when I call the array with `IPAddresses`, I get nullpointerexception (meaning that the array = null).

I call the addresses like this:

```
ManagementObject choosen = (ManagementObject)eInterfacesConfig.Current;
String[] ipAddresses = (String[]) choosen["IPAddress"];
lblIP.Text = ipAddresses[0];
```

`eInterfacesConfig` is a `ManagementObjectCollection.Enumerator` and
choosen is the current `ManagementObject` out of the enumerator.

I try to change the text of a label (lblIP) to the first Ip address in the array. But this is where the exception throws.

Can someone explain why and perhaps point me into the right direction?

Comment: Sorry Soner Gönül, I'll pay attention to that next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns two `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` objects
on my Windows 8 machine:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration  WHERE DHCPEnabled ='TRUE'");

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = query.Get();
queryCollection = query.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject currentConfig in queryCollection)
{
  string[] addresses = (string[])currentConfig["IPAddress"];

  Console.Out.WriteLine(currentConfig["Description"]);
  if (addresses != null)
  {
    foreach (var addr in addresses)
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine(addr);
    }
  }
}
```

The first adapter configuration is for the *Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter*.
This adapter is used for remote kernel debugging. The `DHCPEnabled` property 
for this adapter is `TRUE`. However there are no IP addresses
assigned to this adapter. This is the reason why the `IPAddress` array is null.

The second adapter configuration is for my *Intel Gigabit Network Adapter*. There
are two IP addresses assigned to the adapter.

Another reason why the `IPAddress` array could be null is 
for example a *disconnected wireless network adapter*.

So, in order to solve your `NullReferenceException` you have to check the
`IPAddress` array for null (please see the code above). Use the `Description`
property to identify the adapter configuration.

Comment: Hi, sorry if i wasn't very clear.
In my program, I do have the right adapter in a 'ManagementObject' ('choosen'). It's a Qualcomm wireless network adapter that I am using right now to access the internet.
That's why it's strange that the array is empty and that ip enabled is false

Comment: @RobbieVercammen: OK, I see. Did you enable IPX on your network adapter (what is the value of the IPXEnabled property)?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. IPX is not enabled on any of my adapters

Comment: @RobbieVercammen: If you right click on your network adapter (network sharing center) is the IPv4 and/or IPv6 protocol enabled? How many network adapters does your computer have?

Comment: I forgot... my wireless adapter is included in a bridge for virtual machines!
Do you know what I should do, I don't want to unbridge.